# Why does removing a console.log call from this async function cause it to upload a black image?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've come across some strange behavior recently, and I thought I'd share it with y'all.

I've been working on image uploading for a user profile portion of an application I'm build in React. I had a working system for selecting, cropping/resizing, and uploading an image a user selected, so I started to clean up the code, removing the `console.log`s everywhere. Well, I was disheartened to find that it no longer worked, uploading a purely black image, so I did the obvious—undo my changes until it works again.

All in all I whittled it down to just one line that changed whether it'd work—one, singular `console.log` statement. Below, you'll see a couple *very* similar working and non-working versions. I want to hear why y'all think this happens.

Not Working:

```
const imageBlob: Blob = (await getCroppedImg(imageElement!, crop)) as Blob;
const { data: { requestImageUpload: { putURL, upload: { id: uploadId } } } } = await requestUpload({
    variables: {
        filename: selectedImage?.name!,
        mimetype: imageBlob.type
    }
});

await (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("PUT", putURL, true);
    oReq.onload = function (e) {
        resolve(null);
    };
    oReq.onprogress = function (e) {
        let percent = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
        setUploadProgress(percent);
    };
    oReq.onerror = function (e) {
        reject(null);
    };
    oReq.send(imageBlob);
}))
```

Working:

```
const imageBlob: Blob = (await getCroppedImg(imageElement!, crop)) as Blob;
const { data: { requestImageUpload: { putURL, upload: { id: uploadId } } } } = await requestUpload({
    variables: {
        filename: selectedImage?.name!,
        mimetype: imageBlob.type
    }
});
console.log(imageBlob)
await (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("PUT", putURL, true);
    oReq.onload = function (e) {
        resolve(null);
    };
    oReq.onprogress = function (e) {
        let percent = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
        setUploadProgress(percent);
    };
    oReq.onerror = function (e) {
        reject(null);
    };
    oReq.send(imageBlob);
}))
```

Also Working:

```
let imageBlob: Blob = (await getCroppedImg(imageElement!, crop)) as Blob;
const { data: { requestImageUpload: { putURL, upload: { id: uploadId } } } } = await requestUpload({
    variables: {
        filename: selectedImage?.name!,
        mimetype: imageBlob.type
    }
});

await (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("PUT", putURL, true);
    oReq.onload = function (e) {
        resolve(null);
    };
    oReq.onprogress = function (e) {
        let percent = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
        setUploadProgress(percent);
    };
    oReq.onerror = function (e) {
        reject(null);
    };
    oReq.send(imageBlob);
}))
```

Note in the second: there's a `console.log` call.
Note in the third: I'm using `let` instead of `const`.
There are no errors, and the uploaded image is an actual JPEG with all black pixels and a 72 KB size (this depends on the original image). It also has the same dimensions as the intended image.

Is the blob getting garbage collected while it's still being read from for the upload?

Comment: What's the difference between the 1st and the 3rd code? I can't spot it

Comment: @FZs `const imageBlob` vs `let imageBlob`. I had to use a diff viewer to find it. Functionally, there shouldn't be a difference. I don't see how any of these three will work different to the others. I suspect it's just an intermittent issue, not specific to any of the three pieces of code.

Comment: any errors from typescript?

Comment: No errors thrown and no linting errors either

Comment: The problem is certainly lying in `getCroppedImg`, if I had to take a blind shot I'd say it isn't waiting for `imageElement` 's `load` event, and so sometimes it will work because Chrome stupidly makes cached images available synchronously sometimes, and some other times it just silently fails. You could try to run your code with Firefox, this browser does throw when you try to draw an image that isn't loaded yet.

Comment: @Kaiido The issue is even weirder than that. `getCroppedImg` is absolutely returning a correct image blob. It pulls it form a canvas. Simply adding a `console.log` or changing `const` to `let` fixes the problem. Adding the `console.log` or using `let` works 100% of the time, but it uploads an entirely black image if I use `const` on that first line.

Comment: No not more weirder at all. And I'm sure these have nothing to do with the issue. Please show this getCroppedImg function. The returned blob is black because the image hasn't been drawn on the canvas there, because it wasn't loaded yet and because the blob is a jpeg version of the canvas which doesn't support transparency.

Comment: It almost looks like imageBlob as const isn't initialized untill accessed. You can prove/refuse that if you replace line `console.log(imageBlob)` with just `imageBlob`. I guess something specific to typescript?

Comment: @bigless how can it be specific to TypeScript when it compiles to JavaScript anyway?

Comment: @VLAZ i mean how it is interpreted and compiled to js under the hood.. From js perspective I agree with your first comment.

Comment: @bigless the TS compiler will not impose big semantic changes in this instance. Or most instances, really. The TS compiler tends to do as little transformation work as reasonably possible - most checks are just done at compile time and the code left intact even if it *could* be wrong. As long as the compiler believes the code is safe, it doesn't transform the code. It won't do stuff like eliminating what *seems* like no-ops (e.g., reading a value). You can see [here](https://tsplay.dev/kNrz2N) that the line `x` is left after compilation, even though it's useless.